# FitNesse Eclipse plugin url from Bandxi is not working

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim, selenium-fitnesse-bridge

The URL from Bandxi is not functioning in Eclispe
http://www.bandxi.com/fitnesse/index.html

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an alternate url for the same; and its working!!

```
http://fitnesse-editor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fiteditSite/
```

[image]